# Measurability of the composition of sections and probability measures

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X,Y,Z$ be Polish spaces endowed with their respective Borel sigma algebras, and $\Delta(Y),\Delta(Z)$ be sets of Borel probability measures on $Y$ and $Z$, endowed with the weak*-topologies (and the associated Borel sigma algebra). Hence, $\Delta(Y),\Delta(Z)$ are Polish spaces. Let $f\colon X \times Y \to Z$ be such that, for every $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$, $f(x,\cdot)$ is Borel measurable and $f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous. Let $\mu \in \Delta(Y)$.

Define $F\colon X \to \Delta(Z)$ by
$$ F(x)(B)=\mu \circ [f(x,\cdot)]^{-1}(B) \qquad (x\in X, B \in \mathcal{B}(Z)) $$
where $\mathcal{B}(Z)$ is the borel sigma algebra of $Z$.

My question is: Is there some "standard'' result that proves that $F$ is measurable? Is it obvious?